# Check IP's hitting Azure load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-load-balancer

Is there a way to see the incoming packets and their incoming IP address that are hitting the Azure standard load balancer?

I am trying to do some checks and collect the log records.

Regards,
Marvin Lee

Answer (score 0):

As such there is no tool available in Azure which can allow you to see the incoming IP address in Standard Load Balancer. You need to handle such request programmatically.

Alternatively, you can use **SYN packets metric which describes the volume of TCP SYN packets, which have arrived or were sent for outbound flows that are associated with a specific front end. You can use this metric to understand TCP connection attempts to your service.**

Refer: [Standard load balancer diagnostics with metrics, alerts, and resource health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics#how-do-i-check-inboundoutbound-connection-attempts-for-my-service)